# Convert PineScript v2 to v5 please

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Could you please help me convert my code to Pine Script v5? I found some impressive code for chart analysis, but it's not compatible with my current version. I'd like to integrate it with my code, but it needs to be compatible with Pine Script v5. Would you be able to assist me with this?

```
study(shorttitle="Bollinger Bands V2 [Super Trend]", title="Bollinger Bands V2 [Super Trend]", overlay=true)
 
//########################## Parametre  ########################################
src = input(defval=close, title="Source")
length = input(defval=20, minval=1, title ="Boullinger Bands")
mult = input(defval=2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50)

souc = input(title="Color of the BB with Super Trend", type=bool, defval=false)
Factor=input(title="Super Trend", defval=4, minval=1,maxval = 100)
ATR=input(title="ATR", defval=12, minval=1,maxval = 100)
spt = input(title="View Super Trend on chart", type=bool, defval=false)


//######################## Bollinger Bands #####################################

basis = sma(src, length)
dev = mult * stdev(src, length)
upper = basis + dev
lower = basis - dev

//########################## Super Trend #######################################

Up=hl2-(Factor*atr(ATR))
Dn=hl2+(Factor*atr(ATR))
TUp=src[1]>TUp[1]? max(Up,TUp[1]) : Up
TDown=src[1]<TDown[1]? min(Dn,TDown[1]) : Dn
Trend = src > TDown[1] ? 1: src < TUp[1]? -1: nz(Trend[1],1)
Tsl = Trend==1? TUp: TDown
TslView = spt == true ? Tsl : false
//############################# couleur ##########################################

linecolorATR = Trend == 1 ? green : red
linecolorPrice = src >= basis ? green : red
linecolor = souc == true ? linecolorATR : linecolorPrice

//########################### Affichage ########################################

plot(TslView, color = linecolorATR , style = line , linewidth = 2, title = "SuperTrend")
plot(basis, color=red, transp=75, title="Moving Average")
p1 = plot(upper, color=linecolor, transp=35, title="high band")
p2 = plot(lower, color=linecolor, transp=35, title="Low band")
fill(p1, p2, color=linecolor, transp=95, title="background")
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, try using the Reference Manual and also Pine Script's debugging to fix what are cosmetic changes:

```
//@version=5
indicator(shorttitle="Bollinger Bands V2 [Super Trend]", title="Bollinger Bands V2 [Super Trend]", overlay=true)
 
//########################## Parametre  ########################################
src = input.source(close, "Source")
length = input.int(20, "Bollinger Bands Period", minval=1)
mult = input.float(2.0, "Bollinger Bands Multiple", minval=0.001, maxval=50)

souc = input.bool(false, "Color of the BB with Super Trend")
Factor = input.float(4, "Super Trend", minval=1, maxval = 100)
ATR = input.int(12, "ATR", minval=1, maxval = 100)
spt = input.bool(false, "View Super Trend on chart")


//######################## Bollinger Bands #####################################

basis = ta.sma(src, length)
dev = mult * ta.stdev(src, length)
upper = basis + dev
lower = basis - dev

//########################## Super Trend #######################################

Up = hl2 - (Factor * ta.atr(ATR))
Dn = hl2 + (Factor * ta.atr(ATR))

TUp = 0.0
TDown = 0.0
Trend = 0.0

TUp := src[1] > TUp[1] ? math.max(Up, TUp[1]) : Up
TDown := src[1] < TDown[1] ? math.min(Dn, TDown[1]) : Dn
Trend := src > TDown[1] ? 1 : src < TUp[1] ? -1 : nz(Trend[1], 1)

Tsl = Trend == 1 ? TUp : TDown
TslView = spt ? Tsl : na
//############################# couleur ##########################################

linecolorATR = Trend == 1 ? color.green : color.red
linecolorPrice = src >= basis ? color.green : color.red
linecolor = souc ? linecolorATR : linecolorPrice

//########################### Affichage ########################################

plot(TslView, color = linecolorATR , style = plot.style_line , linewidth = 2, title = "SuperTrend")
plot(basis, color=color.new(color.red, transp=75), title="Moving Average")
p1 = plot(upper, color=color.new(linecolor, transp=35), title="high band")
p2 = plot(lower, color=color.new(linecolor, transp=35), title="Low band")
fill(p1, p2, color=color.new(linecolor, transp=95), title="background")
```